# How To Write Next Line To File

Tags: java, io

I have tried using `writer.newLine()` however it says method not found. Does anyone know how I can write a new line after each iteration?

```
 public static void keepLetters() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        for (String line = sourceReader.readLine(); line != null; line = sourceReader.readLine()) {
            String updatedLine = line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
            System.out.println(updatedLine);

            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                 new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), "UTF-8"))) {
                    writer.write(updatedLine);
            }
        }

    }
```

I wrote `writer.nextLine()` after `writer.write(updatedLine)`;

Thank you

Comment: FYI you are overwriting the file with each line that you read, so it will only output the last line. Either create the `Writer` outside the loop or append to the file instead.

Comment: Change `Writer writer = new BufferedWriter` to `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter` and try again

Comment: If you read the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) you will find that `newLine` is a member of `BufferedWriter`, but you've defined your `writer` to be an instance of `Writer`, which is why the method is not found

Comment: I wrote it outside loop (I think) Its not writing to file now, any ideas how to fix? https://pastebin.com/G2qLTDzU

Comment: @SakshamInABox the code on pastebin works, but you forgot to use `writer.close();` after the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct method is `newLine()`, but you need to call it on a `BufferedWriter`, not a `Writer`.

Like so:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                 new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true), "UTF-8"))) {
                                 writer.write(updatedLine);
                                 writer.newLine();
            }
```

Note this part `try (BufferedWriter writer`

---

Update for comment

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), "UTF-8"));

for (int i = 0; i < linesToWrite; i++){
    writer.write(updatedLine);
    writer.newLine();
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately. My output in console is: ABC DEF GHK However in the file it only shows GHK

Comment: I tried deleting content from file so it was empty and rerunning the code and it still ended up with just GHK on first line

Comment: That is because every time your try method is called it is creating a new `FileOutputStream`, and it will replace it each time, so you will only ever see the last write

Comment: @SakshamInABox The reason you're only getting the last line is because on each iteration of the loop, you're writing overing the file, rather then appending to it, it would be, generally, better to open the file first, then iterate over the text

Comment: MadProgrammer is correct, that is the best way to do it. However depending on your usage you can also append a file by using setting the `true` flag when you create the file write method like so: `new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true)`

Comment: I used the true flag

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do

```
writer.write(updatedLine + "\n");
```

which will ensure a newline is written after every updatedLine.

EDIT:

The writer is being reinitiated to the same file output every iteration of the loop. It should be initialised once before the loop and closed later on to resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried that too, it still only shows the last iteration in the first line

Comment: My output in console is:
ABC
DEF
GHK

However in the file it only shows GHK

Comment: That is because you are opening the file each iteration (for write and not append). Either way, open it once before the loop, and close it when you are done.

Comment: I made it like this it does not write to fill at all now https://pastebin.com/G2qLTDzU. Any ideas where the error is? Thanks

Comment: It would be better for the OP to just define `writer` as a `BufferedWriter` and make use of the `newLine` method or, if pushed to it, [`System.lineSeperator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) rather then hard coding it